# SharePoint 2007 Create Web application from Central Admin doesn't show up in IIS

Tags: central-administration

I'm new to SharePoint.

I know once you create a web application and do a good `iisreset /noforce`

You should be able to see the Application Pool and Website in IIS that you just created in Central Admin.  However, it doesn't show up in IIS.

Furthermore, to make this bug even more bizarre.

The database from the wizard creation is attached to the correct database engine as expected.

And, I can go in and create a site collection as if the web application does exist.

But, when you go to the URL after you create the site collection for that app you get a HTTP 502 Error, because technically it doesn't exist.

Suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to do an IISRESET after creating a webapplication. Maybe you did it to soon while it still was creating the web application so an error occured. I would suggest to delete the old web application and creating it again. And DON'T do an iisreset. Just start creating the sitecollection after the webapplication was created.

Comment: That didn't work.  I did find out that the user account I used to create the Application Pool did not have administrative rights on the box.  A quick change from this and I received the expected results.

Comment: When a web application is provisioned a bunch of timer jobs kick off which finish off the creation of the web application on all the web front ends. Do an IISReset and it will interrupt this process.

Answer (score 0):

In this type of situations, my first step is to always check the logs (ULS logs, Windows Event Logs, IIS logs). Check at the time of the Web application creation what is logged.

In your case, it looks like there was a permission issue. That would have been logged in the log files.